# C++ Number guessing game

Tags: c++

I'm having issues getting this C++ code to work as I'd like.

Its a generic number guessing game, the computer picks a random number the user guesses it. They have 5 attempts and depending on how far their guess is from the correct answer, an output is selected.

The issue is, when the guess is larger than the generated random number. There is no output. The code works correctly if the guess is lower than the random number though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // Used for random num generator
#include <ctime> // Used for the seed

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int> (time(0)));
   const int MAX_NUMBER = 100;
   int num = (rand() % MAX_NUMBER) + 1;
   int tries = 0;   // Number of times player has guessed
   int guess;       // Player's current guess

   cout << "\tGuess my Number" << endl << endl;
   cout << "Guess my number between 1 and ";
   cout << MAX_NUMBER << "." << endl << endl;

   do
   {
       cout << "Enter a guess; ";
       cin >> guess;
       ++tries;

       int diff = (num - guess);

       if (diff >= 50)  // If guess is off by 50 or more
       {
           if (guess < num)
               cout << "Way to Low!\n";
           else
               cout << "Way to high!" << endl;
       }

       if (diff >= 30 && diff < 50) // If guess is off by 30 to 50
       {
           if (guess < num)
               cout << "That guess was rather low!\n";
           else
               cout << "That guess was rather high!" << endl;
       }

       if (diff >= 15 && diff < 30) // If guess is off by 15 to 30
       {
           if (guess < num)
               cout << "That guess was low!\n";
           else
               cout << "That guess was high!" << endl;
       }

       if (diff > 0 && diff < 15) // If the guess is off under 15
       {
           if (guess < num)
               cout << "That guess was some what low.\n";
           else
               cout << "That guess was some what high." << endl;
       }
   } while ((guess != num) && (tries <= 5));

   if (guess == num)
   {
       cout << endl;
       cout << "You win! You got it in " << tries << " tries!";
       cout << endl;
   }
   else {
       cout << endl;
       cout << "You ran out of guesses!" << endl;
   }

   system("pause"); // Used to hold open the output window.
   return 0;
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: if your `guess` is greater than your `num`, your `diff` will be negative, which you don't handle anywhere.

Comment: `abs()` gives the absolute value so `int diff = abs(num-guess);`will fix this. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/

Comment: Thanks, abs did it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in if conditions, if `guess` was greater than `num`, `diff` will be negative but you didn't consider that:

```
if (diff >= 50)
```

You must take `abs` from `(num-guess)` to make it work.

Just change this line:

```
int diff = (num - guess);
```

to

```
int diff = abs(num - guess);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Those three little letters was holding me back :P

Answer (score 1):

Your `diff` equals `num - guess`, which means you end up with a negative value if `guess` is greater than `num`. However, you never check if `diff` is negative so you never enter your conditions

Comment: Thanks, that helped.